# Cannot install Linux distros on old machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, laptop

I have a 10-year-old laptop (HP pavilion dv-6), with Linux mint installed. But now I need to install ubuntu (to create a home server). I am plugging a flash drive with ubuntu ISO on it, select this USB drive in boot menu, but after that I can see only "GRUB" text in the left top corner. And that's all. Nothing happens. I also tried to install Manjaro, but same thing happened. However Mint installed easily.

UPDATE:
`4gb ram, bios, 64bit`

UPDATE 2:
Laptop model: `hp pavilion dv6-6b00st`
.iso file name: `ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso`

I formatted hard drive of laptop into clear one with windows bootable usb, but nothing changed. Also tried writing ISO image with rufus, but it provides only universal mode for both UEFI and BIOS.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it 32 or 64 bits? Is it BIOS or EFI? How much RAM?

Comment: @stark, 64 bit, 4gb ram, BIOS

Comment: Which tool/method did you use to create the USB boot drive? Did you check with sha256sum that the downloaded iso is good? Which version of Ubuntu (name of the iso file)? What graphics chip/card is there in the computer? - Please edit the original question to add all these details including. It makes it easier for us to 'see' your computer and what you have done.

Comment: While I've not installed Ubuntu for a while, most Linux distros use Isolinux to boot from USB/DVD. If it says "Grub" on your screen, that sounds to me like the computer is confused about where it is boot ing from. Check your BIOS.

Comment: If an I-series Intel chip, it is early UEFI. Many vendors still call it BIOS. It may still be best to install in BIOS boot mode, If drive is gpt partitioned, not MBR, you will need a bios_grub partition. Have you tried a server ISO or light weight flavor? https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie  Also Server: https://releases.ubuntu.com/jammy/  and then install just GUI not full desktop.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Dan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/567518/dan) said, it could be an MBR UEFI problem. I had the same problem as you on my old HP 32bit Pentium notebook, and unfortunately I could only solve it by burning a Debian CD/DVD and installing.

If you can not solve it with another disk partition on usb, you can try a CD/DVD version of an iso; it has complete set of packages image files

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this issue only with mini-ubuntu 18.04 iso image from link below: 
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

After installing MinimalCD version, I easily updated to 20.04 and after that to 22.04.

On another HP Pavilion laptop, but few years older with early UEFI problem was solved by manual deleting of EFI partition on bootable usb.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a boot partition on the USB and make sure to select legacy boot, not UEFI, assuming your hardware is old.

Comment: The OP wrote "Also tried writing ISO image with rufus" so I'm going to remove that question from your Answer. In the future (and once you have enough reputation points), please use Comments on the Question to ask for clarification. Answers should be self-contained answers that don't require clarification from the asker. Thank you!